# How to prove $(p \to q) \equiv (\neg q \to \neg p)$ by using natural deduction?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I know that most of us know the contrapositive $$(p \to q) \equiv (\neg q \to \neg p)$$ but how can I prove this by using natural deduction?

Comment: A valid proof is based on a set of inference rules. What is your set of inference rules?

Comment: If you aren't willing to share what you tried on your own behalf, perhaps you'll edit your question to include the set of  inference rules you are working with, and a comment as to where you're stuck.

Comment: What are your rules? We can give you a proof using one set of rules, but if you have a different set of rules, then that proof is no good to you.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

See [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) for the rules.

> A) $p \to q \vdash \lnot q \to \lnot p$

1) $p \to q$

2) $\lnot q$ --- assumed [a]

3) $p$ --- assumed [b]

4) $q$ --- by $\to$-elim

5) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 4) by $\lnot$-elim

6) $\lnot p$ --- from 3) and 5) by $\lnot$-intro, discharging [b]

> 6) $\lnot q \to \lnot p$ --- from 2) and 6) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

---

For the other part, we need *Double Negation* or *LEM*.

Answer (score 1):

I use '~' for '$\lnot$' and '->' for '$\rightarrow$' in the following.  I don't know how to fill in the dots, so you'll have to do that.  Some systems say that when you have a contradiction under the scope of the hypothesis $\lnot$$\alpha$ you can infer $\lnot$$\lnot$$\alpha$.  Some say that under that hypothesis you can infer $\alpha$.  Some say that you can infer that ($\lnot$$\alpha$$\rightarrow$($\beta$$\land$$\lnot$$\beta$)), where ($\beta$$\land$$\lnot$$\beta$) indicates the contradiction.  Then you can infer $\alpha$ from that.  Some say you have to have something like ($\lnot$$\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\beta$) as well as ($\lnot$$\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\lnot$$\beta$), and only then can you infer $\alpha$.  This makes for a good problem to suggest where natural deduction systems generally tend to differ the most.  You'll also have to write the proof analysis.

```
If (p -> q)
    If ~q
         If ~~p
            .
            .
            .
            p
            q
            Contradiction
        .
        .
        .
       ~p 
   (~q -> ~p)
```

((p$\rightarrow$q)$\rightarrow$($\lnot$q$\rightarrow$$\lnot$p))

```
If (~q -> ~p)
     If p
         If ~q
            ~p
            Contradiction
        .
        .
        .
        q
   (p -> q)
```

(($\lnot$q$\rightarrow$$\lnot$p)$\rightarrow$(p$\rightarrow$q))

Now, can you complete a proof?